# Why is JComponent a subclass of Container?

Tags: swing, awt, class-hierarchy

The class [javax.swing.JComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) is a direct subclass of [javax.awt.Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html), which provides [methods to add child components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component)). While this makes sense for some components, like [JTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) or [JTree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html), it doesn't seem to make sense for [JLabel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html), for example. As far as I could tell from simple experiments, children of a `JLabel` are ignored.

Is there a good reason that all `JComponent` subclasses are also subclasses of `Container`, or is it just a relic of the days of overzealous subclassing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is JComponent a subclass of Container?

You can add child components to any component. You may get different behaviour than you would if you add components to a panel, but it can be done. For most components, other than a JPanel, a null layout is used.

> While this makes sense for some components, like JTable or JTree,

Why do you say this. A JTable is just a component. The normal display of a JTable does not have any child components. When you edit a cell, the editor component is added to the table and the table will manage the size/location of the component.

> it doesn't seem to make sense for JLabel, for example. As far as I could tell from simple experiments, children of a JLabel are ignored.

Since the layout is null you need to manage the size/location of any component you add to the label.

Or, you can set the layout manager of the JLabel. Note the actual size of the label will not include the children, but you can position the children on the label using the layout manager.